# Proving that for all sets A, B, A⊆B if and only if A \ B = ϕ (Solved)

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I'm a little stuck on this problem, this is my attempt at a solution. Can anyone tell me if it is correct, or am I doing something wrong:

We need to prove that:

1) If A⊆B then A∖ B=ϕ,  and

2) If  A∖B=ϕ then A⊆B

For 1)

Let us assume A⊆B,

We must prove that A \ B=ϕ,

to do so we must prove A \ B⊆ϕ and ϕ⊆A \ B

Let us first prove A \ B⊆ϕ, for this statement to be true we need to prove that for all x the statement x∈A \ B must be false

if x∈A \ B then x∈A and x∉B,

but x∈B since A⊆B

Therefore, the statement x∈A \ B is false and therefore A \ B⊆ϕ

Now, let us prove ϕ⊆A \ B

We must prove if x∈ϕ then x∈A \ B

Since x∈ϕ is false, then x∈A \ B is true and therefore ϕ⊆A \ B

Since A \ B⊆ϕ and ϕ⊆A \ B, thus A \ B=ϕ

For 2)

Let us assume A∖B=ϕ

Then A∖B⊆ϕ and ϕ⊆A∖B

If A∖B⊆ϕ, then x∉A∖B

We must prove that A⊆B

The statement A⊆B is true if  ∀x:if x∈A then x∈B

This is also equivalent to ∀x:x∉A or x∈B

Since x∉A∖B, then x∉A or x∈B

Therefore, we can say the statement A⊆B is true if A∖B=ϕ

Thus, we have proven, If A⊆B then A∖B=ϕ and if  A∖B=ϕ then A⊆B

Thus, A⊆B if and only if A∖B=ϕ

Comment: Welcome to MSE. My guess is that you meant $A\setminus B$ instead of $A/B$.

Comment: oh yeah, I made a mistake in writing that

Comment: 'Let $x \in A$. Then ...' in the first two lines have to be removed from this proof.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for math formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have so far is fine.  Notice that you were asked to prove that the implication goes in both directions ("if and only if"), so you still have to prove that $A\setminus B=\emptyset$ implies $A\subseteq B$.

When you're asked to prove that $S=\emptyset$, your argument typically won't take the form of a normal set equality proof, since the empty set is special.  First, you never have to prove that $\emptyset\subseteq S$ for your particular set, because that is always true.  Second you don't normally see people writing $x\notin\emptyset$, because again that is obviously always true.  So just let $x\in S$ be an arbitrary member of the set, get a contradiction, and you can jump right to concluding $S=\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you suggest how I can prove A∖B=∅ implies A⊆B, I'm struggling with coming up with the logic for it

Comment: So, your goal is to show that $x\in A$ implies $x\in B$, and you're allowed to use the fact that $x\notin A\setminus B$ (because that set is empty).  Can you flesh it out from there?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to approach this kind of problem  this way:

Let's assume $A \subset B$, so if $x \in A$, then $x \in B$. Take $x \in A \setminus B$, so $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$, since $A \subset B$, then $x \in B$ and $x \notin B$. So $A \setminus B$ must be empty.
Now, let's assume $A \setminus B = \emptyset$, this means that there's no element of $A$ that is not in $B$, hence all elements of $A$ are in $B$, therefore $A \subset B$.

It may seem a little bit heuristic, but it is a valid proof. Sorry for doing it all, but you can use this method to prove basically anything in set theory that way.